# batch for loop changes behaviour after executing mvn call

Tags: batch-file

The following script is executed in the C:\develop\gitrepos\project1 folder with the intention of updating all sub folder git repos and building the source in necesarry, it works up until the first time the mvn call is executed, once that call returns all subsequent for loop processing does not work correctly, the 'if !first! ...' statement does not execute but is simply output to the console.

note also that in earlier versions of the script the third last line would simply do a cd .., but in this version of the script if I do that it would take me to C:\ which is really confusing.

is there any way to cause the for loop to continue executing as normal after the mvn execution ?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for /D %%f in ("*") do @(
        @cd %%f
        @if exist pom.xml @(
                @if exist .git @(
                        echo pulling %%f
                        REM we only want to check the first line
                        set first=T
                        for /F "delims=" %%I in ('git pull --prune') do (
                                if !first!==T (
                                        set first=F
                                        if "%%I"=="Already up-to-date." (
                                                echo         %%f is already up-to-date
                                        ) else (
                                                REM when mvn executes it breaks subsequent for /F do calls
                                                REM the if !first! ... statement is not executed, it is simply
                                                REM output to the console as if it were an echo
                                                (mvn clean install -DskipTests)
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
        @cd C:\develop\gitrepos\project1
)
echo on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `call mvn ...`, that's all.

#### Explanation:

mvn is a batch file itself.

Starting a batch file from another batch file, stops the *caller* script and there will no return to the *caller*.

But you used a command block in a FOR loop and command blocks are cached, therefore the FOR loop itself continues to loop (even without returning to the *caller* script).

But when the mvn ends, the batch context ends, too.
Then `cmd.exe` uses the command line context, with slightly different rules.
And it enables the `ECHO ON` mode again.

Using `call` is required when calling batch files, then the return mechanism works as expected.

Comment: wow - ive been pulling my hair out every morning for the last few days on that - thanks